# Blazor Client Side Breakpoints

Tags: blazor-client-side

I've followed all the steps as detailed by microsoft here: 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.0' on debugging a Blazor WebAssembly and yet no matter what project I try it with, although I can open the various client side files in the dev tools window it will not let me set any breakpoints. I've tried it with both the latest Chrome (77.0.3865.120) and the latest Microsoft Edge preview. Does anyone know what I have missed?